# PhraseExpress Symbols doesn't revert back to original font. How to fix?

Tags: fonts, phraseexpress

I use PhraseExpress to quickly add symbols which is great.  But afterwards, the font doesn't return back to its original font.  For example, if I type something like this ==>, PhraseExpress will convert it into ➔ which is a Windings font.  When I continue typing, the font is now set at Windings font and I'll be typing symbol characters.  I have to manually change the font back to the original font.

Is there a way to make PhraseExpress automatically to revert back to the original font?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's PhraseExpress that does this? Do you have the same error when PhraseExpress is off? Word has this function as well and actually does change the font. It turns the => into an arrow bullet point.

When saving snippets in PhraseExpress it is usually best to remove formatting and save the phrase as plain text. Make sure the symbol has no formatting when saving it in PhraseExpress by selecting "Plain text". If it already has text, right click on the field that says "Formatted phrase content" and click on "Remove text formatting". This should solve the issue with switching the font.

Comment: I deliberately turned off AutoCorrect in Msft Word because of possible conflicts.  The only thing I didn't turn off was Capitalization of Sentences because PhraseExpress seems to miss them for bullets and listings.  If the symbol has no formatting, it won't look right.  For rexample, ==> which changes to a right arrow will change into either a tiny right arrow or a square.